# Integer casting within arithmetic expressions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting

In the following Kotlin code example I expected the value of parameter `i` to be equal to `0`, such as is the case for the parameter `k`. The IDE reports all `i`, `j` and `k` as `Int`. Is it a bug or do I need to readjust my understanding of Kotlin casting inside expressions?  For example, is there a rule to always promote/cast to `Double` inside expressions involving division, but not multiplication?

```
fun main() {
    //Kotlin 1.3.61
    val x = 100 * 1.0/100 //Double
    val i = 100 * 1/100 //Int
    val j = 1/100   //Int
    val k = 100 * j //Int
    println(x) //1.0
    println(i) //1
    println(j) //0
    println(k) //0
}
```

Comment: * and / have equal precedence so they are applied from left to right. That's why `i` is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expected the value of parameter i to be equal to 0

The output is arithmetically right: `100 * 1 / 100 = (100 * 1) / 100 = 100 / 100 = 1 / 1 = 1`

> , such as is the case for the parameter k.

The value `j` is `0`, so anything multiplied by it will be zero, as in case of `k`.

> is there a rule to always promote/cast to Double inside expressions
>   involving division, but not multiplication?

If you divide integers, you will get an integer back. If one of the numbers is a Double, the result will be a Double:

```
 val x = 100 * 1.0/100 //Double because 1.0 is a Double
```

--

There is actually already a discussion on kotlin forum to your problem [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/dividing-integers/1662):

> Mathematically speaking the current behaviour is correct.
>   This is called integer devision and results in the quotient as an
>   answer